# Hardware RAID Level

Tags: raid, megacli

I believe I may have set up wrongfully using RAID-1 instead of RAID-10. Can anyone advise from this output?

```
[root@banjo ~]# ./lsi.sh drives
Slot Number: 0 - Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 1 - Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 2 - Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 3 - Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 4 - Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 5 - Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 6 - Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 7 - Online, Spun Up
[root@banjo ~]# ./lsi.sh status


Adapter 0 -- Virtual Drive Information:
Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)
Name :
RAID Level : Primary-1, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size : 14.552 TB
Sector Size : 512
Is VD emulated : Yes
Mirror Data : 14.552 TB
State : Optimal
Strip Size : 1.0 MB
Number Of Drives per span:4
Span Depth : 2
Default Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAhead, Cached, No Write Cache if
Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAhead, Cached, No Write Cache if
Bad BBU
Default Access Policy: Read/Write
Current Access Policy: Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy : Disabled
Encryption Type : None
Bad Blocks Exist: No
PI type: No PI

Is VD Cached: No



Exit Code: 0x00
###############################################

Adapter 0: Patrol Read Information:

Patrol Read Mode: Disabled
Patrol Read Execution Delay: 168 hours
Number of iterations completed: 0
Next start time: 01/03/2015, 03:00:00
Current State: Stopped
Patrol Read on SSD Devices: Disabled

Exit Code: 0x00
###############################################

Check Consistency on VD #0 is not in progress.

Exit Code: 0x00
[root@banjo ~]#
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to interpret this output from MegaCli?](https://serverfault.com/questions/385796/how-to-interpret-this-output-from-megacli)

Answer (score 0):

Given the output here: `RAID Level : Primary-1, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0`, coupled with `Span Depth : 2`, it looks like you're running RAID 10. [This may be helpful as well.](https://serverfault.com/questions/595005/raid-level-confusion-megacli-vs-megasasctl-output)